# How to select 2 options in drop down in one step using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, webdriver, protractor

We have a scenario for example https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview under multiple selection heading we want to select 2 options like mushroom and onion in single step how can we achieve this.

Currently I am doing this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-option-text', 'Extra cheese')).click();
```

it is running perfectly.

But I need something like:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-option-text', 'Extra cheese,Mushroom')).click();
```

I want to select Mushroom and extra cheese in one single step.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, is it not possible to do `element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-option-text', 'Extra cheese')).click();` then `element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-option-text', 'Mushroom')).click();`? I am not sure Protractor can do 2 simultaneous actions in the same browser, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Actually the idea was to give option text as data source and code will select options from dropdown in single step like code should be written in such a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by using loop:

```
it("TEST DROPDOWN MULTI SELECT", function () {
    var data = 'Extra cheese,Mushroom';
    result1 = data.split(",");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < result1.length; i++) {
        element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-option-text', result1[i])).click();
    }
    browser.sleep(10000);
});
```